# addition in if else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

need to do addition in the if else loop if the value more than A >= 360000. And yet when been applied the elif, only the first condition A >= 180000, is displayed.

```
A = int(input('Price of Property: '))

if A >= 180000:
    A = 180000*0.1 
    break
    print(A)

elif A >= 360000:
    break
    A = (180000*0.1) +(180000*0.2)
    print(A)

else:
    print('invalid')
```

Comment: That's because anything that's greater than `360000` will always be greater than `180000`.  Try inverting the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

That's because anything that's greater than 360000 will always be greater than 180000. Try inverting the conditions. Also, please place your `break` statements correctly.

The below code should meet your requirements.

```
A = int(input('Price of Property: '))

if A >= 360000:
   ...

elif A >= 180000:
   ...
else:
   print('invalid')
```